# R Studio Version 1.2.5033 - problem installing packages Part 1

Tags: r, installation, package

On a Opensuse machine, I tried installing the "alr3" package. It failed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yQCm.png)

```
> install.packages("alr3")
Installing package into ‘/home/by79/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘SparseM’, ‘curl’, ‘minqa’, ‘nloptr’, ‘statmod’, ‘RcppEigen’, ‘pbkrtest’, ‘quantreg’, ‘rio’, ‘lme4’, ‘car’


* installing *source* package ‘SparseM’ ...
** package ‘SparseM’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fpic  -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection  -c bckslv.f -o bckslv.o
make: gfortran: Command not found
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:190: bckslv.o] Error 127
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘SparseM’
* removing ‘/home/by79/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.0/SparseM’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘SparseM’ had non-zero exit status
* installing *source* package ‘curl’ ...
** package ‘curl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Package libcurl was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libcurl.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libcurl' found
Using PKG_CFLAGS=
Using PKG_LIBS=-lcurl
------------------------- ANTICONF ERROR ---------------------------
Configuration failed because libcurl was not found. Try installing:
 * deb: libcurl4-openssl-dev (Debian, Ubuntu, etc)
 * rpm: libcurl-devel (Fedora, CentOS, RHEL)
 * csw: libcurl_dev (Solaris)
If libcurl is already installed, check that 'pkg-config' is in your
PATH and PKG_CONFIG_PATH contains a libcurl.pc file. If pkg-config
is unavailable you can set INCLUDE_DIR and LIB_DIR manually via:
R CMD INSTALL --configure-vars='INCLUDE_DIR=... LIB_DIR=...'
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘curl’
* removing ‘/home/by79/R/x86_64-suse-linux-gnu-library/4.0/curl’
```

The rest may be too long to post but is the above sufficient for some clues? Is it because of the compiler issue....how can I go about fixing it?

Please help.

Comment: It seems unlikely that your console warnings/errors would have started immediately with that, normally there are `gcc` warnings/errors that trigger that failure. Whenever there are failures in dependencies, follow-on package-installation failures are almost certainly directly related, either due to the same reason (e.g., broken/missing compiler) or because that first package is not available (as a requirement for others' installation). Please include the *beginning* of the failure messages, as your answer (or the next big clue) will most likely be in there.

Comment: Thanks r2evans, I edited my post. Would this provides more clues?

Comment: Yes: *"make: gfortran: Command not found"* identifies a **critical** component that is missing: the compiler. Go to https://cloud.r-project.org/ or one its [mirrors](https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html), click on "Download R for Linux", click on your distro, and then read the README. I think you're on suse, so perhaps https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/suse/README.html.

Comment: BTW, it looks like you're also going to need at least one other linux (not R) package to support `libcurl`. Look at the `dev` or `rpm` packages needed under "anticonf error".

Comment: Thanks r2evans, I think this give me some pointers on what to do next.